# I'm not able to access github repository from vscode

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

I'm new to Git: I was trying to integrate it with VSCode, but getting this error

```
git clone https://github.com/vijaypatneedi/DS.git f:\VS Code\DSA\DS
Cloning into 'f:\VS Code\DSA\DS'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/vijaypatneedi/DS.git/': Unsupported proxy syntax in '<proxy-server-url>:<port>'
```

Comment: The last parameter of a git clone is just a directory name, not a full path. See [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt-ltdirectorygt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not seem to be a VSCode clone issue, but rather a cURL issue, like [winlibs/cURL issue 14](https://github.com/winlibs/cURL/issues/14)

Check first if you have defined a proxy (`env|grep -i proxy`).

As stated, the syntax might be incorrect.

---

If this is not linked to the proxy itself, it then depends on your `curl` version currently installed.

```
where curl
```

It can be:

- the one from Windows 10 (`C:\Windows\System32\curl.exe`)
- the one from Git (`C:\path\to\Git\mingw64\bin\curl.exe`)

Try and launch VSCode in a CMD where you have set a simplified PATH:

```
set PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
set GH=C:\path\to\git
set PATH=%GH%\bin;%GH%\usr\bin;%GH%\cmd;%GH%\mingw64\bin;%PATH%
```

With `C:\path\to\git` a folder where you have uncompressed the latest Git [`PortableGit-2.23.0-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.23.0.windows.1/PortableGit-2.23.0-64-bit.7z.exe)

Then type:

```
"%LOCALAPPDATA%\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin\code.cmd"
```