# Git: git@gitlab.com: Permission Denied (publickey) when I press "synchronize changes" button

Tags: git, ssh, visual-studio-code, gitlab

I use windows and cmder and have the default terminal set to cmder's bash term (I believe it's whatever version of git-for-windows that ships with cmder).
I also have a password protected ~/.ssh/id_ed25519 ssh key file.

Here is my ~/.ssh/config file although I've tried almost every possible setting for this file already.

```
Host gitlab.com
HostName gitlab.com
User git
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519`
```

I've also tried

```
Host *
HostName gitlab.com
User git
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519`
```

I have been working on this for a really long time now and it appear there's not really any good information out there on this topic. No matter how I set this up it always says "Git: git@gitlab.com: Permission Denied (publickey)" when I press the synchronize changes button in the lower left corner.

I have tried everything that I have found on a multitude of forums including making sure "`remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal`": is set to "`true`" and doing almost every possible configuration of `~/.ssh/config`.

When I run "`git pull`" or "`git push`" from the terminal, it prompts me for the password to my keyfile and I type the password and it works fine.
For some reason whenever I hit that synchronize changes button I get the same error "`Git: git@gitlab.com: Permission Denied (publickey).`"

Also, I already have "ssh-agent" running and I have my keyfile added to ssh-agent as an identity. So when I type "`ssh-add -l`" it does give me the correct keyfile information.

So to summarize the key facts:

1. When I run git pull/push/..., it promps me for my password and works fine
2. When I press "Synchronize changes", it gives me the error message
   `Git: git@gitlab.com: Permission Denied (publickey)`

Answer (score 1):

Check first the remote URL used by VSCode when it pull or push:
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>: Git: show Git output

Double-check the remote URL used by your local repository

```
cd /path/to/repo
git remote -v
```

I would use as URL

```
git remote set-url origin gitlab.com:<me>/<myrepo>
```

No need for git@ since your `~/.ssh/config` is supposed to provide it for you.
Actually, I would change in that `~/.ssh/config` file the Host entry from gitlab.com to gitlab and:

```
git remote set-url origin gitlab:<me>/<myrepo>
```

That way, you are sure to be using the SSH config file.

I would also test the authentication with

```
ssh -T gitlab
ssh -Tvvv gitlab
```

(Use the second form only if the first fails)

Comment: Thanks for the the help and there's a lot of great information here. but for some reason vscode stopped letting me use ssh at all. Now when I try to clone a repo in the first place it just gives me the error "cannot spawn --get-all: No such file or directory" and "fatal: unable to fork" when I try to initially clone my repositories. My command is "git clone git@gitlab.com/.../...git" Lol git and ssh are really not cooporating with me today.

Comment: @ChristianOConnor Check the %PATH% used when you are launching VSCode. Maybe Git is not correctly referenced there. I use typically a simplified path as in here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58254413/6309

Comment: I don't think it's a %PATH% issue. I'm using vscode with cmder's bash terminal (git for windows terminal) and I can do `git clone https://gitlab.com/.../...git` and clone the repo just fine, but for some reason when the command is `git clone git@gitlab.com/.../...git` instead of `git clone https://gitlab.com/.../...git` it fails.

Comment: @ChristianOConnor What does `set|grep -i ssh` returns? Do you have any "ssh" environment variable?

Comment: wow, it returned a ton of stuff but I think the relevant things you're looking for are 
`/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH`
`PLINK_PROTOCOL=ssh`

I think the problem lies in `/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH` right? I want to use cmder's version of ssh aka `/usr/bin/ssh` not `/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH`

One other thing that's weird is when I type `which ssh` I get `/usr/bin/ssh`

Comment: PLINK? last tile I saw it, it was 2012: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11273633/6309. No `GIT_SSH`?

Comment: wow, it returned a ton of stuff but I think the relevant things you're looking for are /c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH PLINK_PROTOCOL=ssh I think the problem lies in /c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH right? I want to use cmder's version of ssh aka /usr/bin/ssh not /c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH One other thing that's weird is when I type which ssh I get /usr/bin/ssh

Comment: Also no `GIT_SSH`

Comment: Not sure. I use the ssh coming with git, which is why I always set a simplified path, as suggested before.

Comment: I tried to manually set the GIT_SSH path. I did `export GIT_SSH="/usr/bin/ssh"` and that still gave me the same error. BTW I get this error even when I try to clone in a cmder terminal outside of vscode. Any thoughts?

Comment: @ChristianOConnor As I mentioned, the first test is try a  CMD session with a simplified PATH: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58254413/6309

Comment: I tried a version of your post slightly modified for a bash terminal:

I opened vscode and used the bash terminal (within vscode) to run
`export PATH=/c/Windows/System32:/c/Windows:/c/Windows/System32/wbem:/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/`

`export GH=/mingw64/bin/git`

`export PATH=$GH/bin:$GH/usr/bin:$GH/cmd:$GH/mingw64/bin:$PATH`

Then I ran `/mingw64/bin/git clone git@gitlab.com/../..git` and I got exactly the same error.

`error: cannot spawn --get-all: No such file or directory
error: cannot spawn --get-all: No such file or directory
fatal: unable to fork`

Comment: Just for testing, would that work in a CMD session?

Comment: Still won't work. I opend CMD and typed
`PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\`
`set GH=C:\tools\Cmder\vendor\git-for-windows`
`set PATH=%GH%\bin;%GH%\usr\bin;%GH%\cmd;%GH%\mingw64\bin;%PATH%`
`"C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe"`
and I still got the same error when I tried `git clone git@gitlab.com/../..git` in the vscode terminal. Keep in mind my vscode terminal is still a bash terminal because I have vscode hartdcoded to use bash. I used a cmd windows to do every command before vscode was opened.

Comment: @ChristianOConnor Did you relaunch VSCode from that CMD session?

Comment: @ChristianOConnor Does `ssh -T gitlab` works from the CMD with the simplified PATH?