# VS Code doesnt pull / push to devops

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I installed git version as written here https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/44244#issuecomment-368250055. I do teams sign in in VS code but still doesn't work.
Over git bash everything is working OK. I can commit, pull, push to devops repo, but over VS code, I can commit changes and I can see branches, but once I want to push my changes to devops I get an error :

> Permission denied, please try again.
> Permission denied, please try again.
> git@ssh.dev.azure.com: Permission denied (password,publickey).
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Then I go again to git, write git push, put my password for keys and my commited changes in VS code are pushed to devops. Any hint, tips, whatever?

Thank you

Comment: If you are using an SSH key instead of username and password, check your personal access tokens in DevOps to make sure the one you are using has write permissions to the repository.

Comment: PAT has Full Access

Answer (score 0):

To know more about this error, launch code (VSCode) from a shell session where you have set `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` to `ssh -v`.

You can then use the VSCode command: "`Git: Show Git output`" to see exactly what your ssh call is doing on git pull/push within VSCode.

[`microsoft/vscode` issue 100774](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/100774) mentions:

> Resolved by forcing GIT to use Win32 OpenSSH instead, through `GIT_SSH_COMMAND`

So check which ssh is used in your case (`ssh -v` will show you that, as [I did here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47322424/6309))

If you have a private key protected by a passphrase, see [How can I use Windows' built-in OpenSSH ssh-agent in VS Code, instead of Git bash's?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60821774/6309), and check the `remote.SSH.path` setting.

Comment: I followed "If you have a private key protected by a passphrase, see How can I use Windows' built-in OpenSSH ssh-agent in VS Code, instead of Git bash's?, and check the remote.SSH.path setting." but no change. I am using passphrase so i did it, but stil doesnt work.

Comment: @kubinho20 Are you on Windows? With the latest Git?

Comment: Yes windows 10, git version 2.28.0.windows.1

Comment: @kubinho20 Can you update Git to 2.30, and then launch vscode from a CMD with a simplified PATH, as shown in https://stackoverflow.com/a/58254413/6309? (for testing)

Comment: updated, but nothing. Btw i tried in VS 2019 and works fine. At least i have to on the push or pull every time putting passphrase for SSH connection , but at least do working. VS code nope.. Any other idea please?

Comment: Looks like problem is, that field where should i put passphrase doesnt appear, so thats i dont have a permission to do pull or push

Comment: @kubinho20 Can you try with a private key *not* protected by a passphrase, for testing?

Comment: Have some guidance how to not protect private key with passphrase if its already protected?

Comment: @kubinho20 Yes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58052425/6309